# Inserting xml values in table no success

Tags: php, sql, sql-insert

Trying to get my xml feed into a table, missing something as not working.

> Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   /Users/John/Sites/XMLproject/Update Emperor.php on line 77

```
//Database variables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Something";
$password = "Very secret";
$dbname = "TestDB";
$temptable = "wlbvx_jb_xml_emperor";

//Open database
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully to database: ","<strong>",$dbname,"</strong>","<br>" ;
?><br><?php
    $url = "http://bookings.emperordivers.com/webScheduleSpecificXML_all.asp";
    $feed = file_get_contents($url);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($feed);

    //Row by row into variable, then into table 
    foreach ($xml->Schedule as $row) {
        $ID = "Null";
        $start = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row->Start));
        $duration = $row->Duration;
        $boat = $row->Boat;
        $itinerary = $row->Itinerary;
        $spaces = $row->Spaces;
        $rateseur = round(str_replace(',', '', $row->Rates->Rate[0]));
        $rategbp = round(str_replace(',', '', $row->Rates->Rate[1]));
        $rateusd = round(str_replace(',', '', $row->Rates->Rate[2]));
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $temptable (id,xml_date, xml_duration, xml_boat, xml_itinerary, xml_spaces, xml_rate_eur, xml_rate_gbp, xml_rate_usd)VALUES ('{$ID}',{$start}', '{$duration}', '{$boat}', '{$itinerary}','{$spaces}', '{$rateseur}', '{$rategbp}', '{$rateusd}')";
        echo "SQL Query to execute:",$sql,"<br>";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
```

What could cause the issue?

Comment: Is that all the code on the page? If so, you have no database connection. In fact, there are several variables that are not defined in your example code.

Comment: Is `$conn` defined? Or simply removed in the example?

Comment: No, not all code, have database connection ($conn) working $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully to database: ","<strong>",$dbname,"</strong>","<br>" ;

Comment: Do you get the success message? Why don't you update your question with all relevant code? (Obviously strip out any sensitive information)

Comment: where is $temptable defined?

Comment: No, see first post for warning message. Line 77 is of course the forelast line in the code dispayed.

Comment: John, the warning message doesn't help us because we don't have all relevant code. We are not mind readers, we need to see the rest of the code so we can come to a conclusion

Comment: $temptable is defined on top of document, after which this table is successful created in mysql

Comment: Just edited the question!

Comment: Found the issue! As above was part of longer code, found that the connection was dropped earlier!